# Is initializing a vector using `std::transform` + parallel execution policy more memory intensive compared to more traditional methods?

Tags: c++, vector, parallel-processing, initialization, std

I have a very large vector `vector<T> t_vec`.

I have a class `U`, which implements a constructor with signature `U(T x)`.

I can create `vector<U> u_vec` using two methods:

A)

```cpp
vector<U> u_vec(t_vec.size());
std::transform(std::execution::parallel_policy, 
    t_vec.begin(), 
    t_vec.end(), 
    u_vec.begin(), 
    [](T& t) { return U(t); }
);
```

B)

```cpp
vector<U> u_vec(t_vec.begin(), t_vec.end());
```

Should I expect method A) to be more memory intensive than method B)?

Comment: Does `U` also have a default constructor and an assignment operator? Method (A) relies on those.

Comment: I don't see why (A) should use any more memory than (B). I suppose it may use `O(1)` extra memory simply because it works with several temporary `U` instances at once.

Comment: Starting threafs do need extra memory, if only for stack space.  At least 4K per thread, plus other thread data allocated by the kernel.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy -- that might matter, but typically, parallel algorithms use a thread pool, where the threads have already been created. Creating threads on the fly for a parallel algorithm would add time overhead.

Comment: PeteBecker.  I agree.  But we have to keep in mind the thread pool is created on demand, and eventually times out when not in use. @user89 If that could be an issue, calling async() from time to time keeps the threads up and ready.

Answer (score 1):

In modern C++, if

```
auto f = [](T& t) { return U(t); };
```

and we do this:

```
std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(U), alignof(U)> buffer;
T t;
::new( (void*)&buffer ) U( f(t) );
```

the return value of `f` is elided directly into the buffer.

As [evidence](https://godbolt.org/z/55s6on) you can see a compiler doing so without calling a move constructor.

This showed up in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) as "guaranteed elision".

Now, there can be some memory overhead in your code; `parallel_policy` implies the use of multiple threads, and managing such threads requires non-zero memory.  But it will **not** allocate multiple `std::vector`s or more instances of `U` or more storage for said `U`s than the non-parallel version.

I believe (with only 80% confidence) that the threads used for the `parallel_policy` must be logically recreated (as in, have different `thread_local`), but OS-level threads can be reused for multiple such calls (a pool).  Tracking said `thread_local` state, maintaining such a pool, etc are going to use a fixed amount of memory per thread, and if you had code that never used threads using `parallel_policy` is going to increase the total memory footprint of your program by O(# of cores).

Comment: Your first example is not applicable, since `std::transform` calls `U::operator=` rather than any constructor (so does materialise a temporary)